# How to run Call Directory Extension?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios10, callkit

I'm working on Call Directory Extension. This extension was added, however I don't have any idea to execute this. Excuted this extension, and 'Choose an app to run' appeared, selected my main app, but it didn't seem to run. Of course added this app on Settings - Phone - Call Blocking & Identification.

I just added extension, and didn't write any code on both of the main app and extension. Do I need to add some code? Searched for several hours, couldn't find solution. Please help.

Comment: How did you know that it didn't run? Are you trying to hit debug points?

Comment: Checked with UserDefaults. And the ids, added in, don't show up when I got call from the numbers. Block number neither.

Comment: See this Answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44266392/7576100

Answer (score 2):

Call directory extension is just a new scheme which is about to add with Main application. 
You just need to enable your application from settings menu as -

> Go to Settings->Phone->Call blocking & identification->Enable your
>   App.

Hence there is nothing like "Choose with app" like things

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, make sure you have added **country code** in the numbers you are using in the code.

And then follow these steps :

1) Delete the app from the device.

2) Run the app from Xcode setting the scheme of your main app. This will launch the app on your device.

3) Then change the scheme to your extension’s target and then run again.

Wait for a minute (as extension takes time to load) and then call from the number that you have provided the ID for. The call screen should display the corresponding name.

If the above steps don’t work,
Go to **Settings -> General -> Reset -> Reset All Settings.** This will clear all the settings on the device. Once this is done, do the above steps again.

This worked for me. If it helps, let me know